Inter-rater reliability coefficients that support fully crossed study designs
I need to calculate the inter-rater reliability of a study performed with about 100 raters over 12 study objects.
The ratings are nominal data with no order or ranking.
According to Hallgren 2012 for cases where the raters not randomly sampled for each subject, Fleiss' Kappa is not an option.
Instead he suggests using Light's kappa or Davies & Fleiss’s kappa instead.
However, Gwet 2014 discourage using Light's kappa, since "averaging multiple pairwise kappa coefficient will yield a measure with no clear meaning".
For Davies & Fleiss’s kappa, I couldn't find any implementation in R that I could use.
It remains unclear if other coefficient recommended in Gwet's handbook like Conger's Kappa, Gwet's AC1 or Krippendorf's Alpha are suitable for fully crossed designs as well.
Or is the study design not that much of an issue in the end?

Is this substantially different from your other question? If not, please try to combine them into one.

I think so. Originally I tried to combine them into one questions, but I noticed that they are dealing with different topics. This one is about the overall assumptions of some IRR metrics when applied within one group of raters. In the other question, I am trying to investigate differences in agreement between two groups of raters, but I am not sure if there exists a method that matches my needs.

Ah, ok, got it! Yeah, nominal is trickier, but an average is an average, though I'm not familiar with Gwet 2014. I don't know ho much difference there is between Fleiss's kappa and Cohen's but you could start here with chasing the references Revelle has here: https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/kappa.html

Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this will help me, since most publications don't explicitly talk about the study design assumptions (at least in the paper Conger 1980, I couldn't find that.)
